# Chrome debugger pops up on script for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I am working on a script that runs fine without any errors in the console. All the DOM elements build correctly when there's an interaction in the page.

However, sometimes when I apply certain tools to some selected elements (utilities that are created by the script), especially when there's a large number of them and the browser seems to handle a somewhat heavy workload, the debugger pops up and points me to a variable declared in the script. It's something simple like `let indexCarry = 0;`.

This only happens if I have Dev Tools opened while testing the script.
I don't have any settings configured for the debugger to pop up, it's all default. And I'm not calling it from the script either.
And if I close the Dev Tools, then it doesn't pop up, everything runs fine.

Is it possible that the debugger shows up even when there's no issue, but the script could exceed some amount of RAM allotted by Chrome to a tab? I imagine that something is exceeded in terms of performance and the browser developers enabled this to point to something (maybe something with the heap?), while not explicitly showing any particular error.

Comment: Are you sure there are no breakpoints set?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I have checked in VS Code by going into View > Open view... > Breakpoints, which opens a tab where any breakpoints should be seen. There is none shown there. And none enabled at the location pointed by the debugger.

Comment: Check in the chrome browser itself. If you open the Dev Tools and goto the sources tab on the right side there should be a breakpoints panel that will list any breakpoints that are set from the browser. Those and the `debugger;` statement are the only ways I know could trigger the debugger.

Comment: Now I see that the Block section in the Breakpoints tab in Chrome Dev Tools says: `indexCarry: <value unavailable>`. Even though the debugger window is popped and points at the ` let indexCarry = 0` variable declaration. It is not clear why it does that. Especially since there's no issue whatsoever if I just close the Dev Tools, the script will run fine.

Comment: @PatrickEvans - There was a line that had this blue pointer flag, clicked on it and disabled it. And yeah there was something with a check mark, an entry in the breakpoints list. Cleared that too and now it seems to not pop up anymore. It's weird because I never enabled a breakpoint. But if this was the cause, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Yes the blue pointer flag is the indicator that that line was set as a breakpoint. You can accidently set them without realizing it, I have done it quite a bit.